# Sort by frequency without deleting lines?

Tags: sort

How can I sort by frequency without deleting any?

```
one
two
one
```

to

```
one
one
two
```

The output of the standard sort-by-frequency `:%!sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` is

```
   2 one
   1 two
```

It has deleted all the copies of the line (bc of `uniq`), and the spaces and numbers are not desired in the output.

So how can I sort by frequency and keep all lines in VIM?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25347941/14467607) will help you.

Comment: Is there a reason, you cannot use `:sort` command?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt no

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21130/10604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your current pipeline is always in the format

```
[zero or more spaces][number of repetitions][space][actual line contents]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         First field: $1         Remaining fields: $2, $3...
```

We can thus set up a for-loop that prints the actual line contents $1 times.

If the file is as simple as you make it look (each line only contains one word), use

```
:%!sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{for(i=$1;i>0;i--)print $2}'
```

Otherwise (this is the **general answer**), use

```
:%!sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{n=$1;sub(/ *[0-9]+ +/,"");for(i=n;i>0;i--)print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mostly vimscript way. Start with your pipeline:

```
:%!sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Now, either

- use a `:global` to delete the number and the line, then repeatedly paste

```
:global/./execute 'normal! 0"adawdd' | let @a = str2nr(@a) | execute 'normal!' @a.'P'
```

- somewhat shorter, but may break depending on the number format (*e.g.*, `010` becomes `8`)

```
:global/./execute 'normal! ^"adiwdd' | execute 'normal!' @a.'P'
```

- use a substitute with `\=` to compute the replacement

```
:%substitute/^\s*\(\d\) \(.*\)/\=repeat([submatch(2)], submatch(1)->str2nr())->join("\n")
```